# How to hide UICollectionView Cell in ios after specific time. eg. Half Hour, 7 week etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch

I going to hide a cell after half an hour time interval from populating time. If app is in not running state then also performs the same operation. Please Help me. Thank's in advance.

Comment: you can use nsnotification to fire a function after stipulated time .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function `delay` that can help you to process delays even in background state (delay will be processed immediately after app becomes active if time is ok). And with this code you can easy cancel this delay if needed But this solution will not work for the situation when the app is not running (for this case I will give another solution):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

typealias dispatch_cancelable_closure = (_ cancel : Bool) -> Void

@discardableResult
func delay(_ time:TimeInterval, closure: @escaping ()->Void) ->  dispatch_cancelable_closure? {

//    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(Int(time * 1000))) {
//        closure()
//    }
//    
//    return nil

    func dispatch_later(_ clsr:@escaping ()->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
            deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(time * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: clsr)
    }

    var closure:(()->Void)? = closure
    var cancelableClosure:dispatch_cancelable_closure?

    let delayedClosure:dispatch_cancelable_closure = { cancel in
        if closure != nil {
            if (cancel == false) {
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    closure?()
//                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure!)
//                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure as! @convention(block) () -> Void);
            }
        }
        closure = nil
        cancelableClosure = nil
    }

    cancelableClosure = delayedClosure

    dispatch_later {
        if let delayedClosure = cancelableClosure {
            delayedClosure(false)
        }
    }

    return cancelableClosure;
}

func cancel_delay(_ closureToCancel:dispatch_cancelable_closure?) {

    if closureToCancel != nil {
        closureToCancel!(true)
    }
}
```

But for case when your application is not running, you need to save the time when you want to remove the cell in NSDefaults before application comes into background, and when application becomes active you can use this delay function to set the rest of the time (or if time expired you can remove the cell immidiatly)